# CTRL+H not calling ditation toolbar on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to use windows new Dictation feature, holding down CTRL and H keys, but no listening toolbar shows as it is supossed to.

The PC just receive the windows 10 April build.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use windows new Dictation feature, holding down CTRL
>   and H keys, but no listening toolbar shows as it is supposed to.

You are using the wrong keyboard shortcut.  You are supposed to use Windows+H

> Windows 10’s Fall Creators Update makes voice dictation much easier to
>   use. Now, you can immediately begin dictation by pressing a key
>   Windows+H on your keyboard. You don’t have to dig through the Control
>   Panel and set anything up first.

[How to Use Voice Dictation on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/331072/how-to-use-voice-dictation-on-windows-10/)

Comment: There is nothing mapped nor has there ever been anything mapped to `CTRL+H ` by default in any version of Windows.   However, within (IE11, Edge, Firefox, and Chrome), it brings up your browser history.